# After starting My Scraper I do not get an output

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am running a scraper to retrieve Product name, Cat No, Size and Price but when I run the script it doesn't give me an output or an error message. I am using Jupyter Notebook for this and not sure if that is the problem. I am also not sure if because I am imputing this into a CSV file if this is also giving it issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code that I am running.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\kevin.cragin\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\09\14\7d\1dcfcf0fa23dbb52fc459e5ce620000e7dca7aebd9300228fe') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.biolegend.com/en-us/advanced-search?GroupID=&PageNum=1')
html = driver.page_source

containers = html.find_all('li', {'class': 'row list'})

with open("BioLegend_Crawl.csv", "w") as f:

    f.write("Product_name, CatNo, Size, Price\n")

    for container in containers:

        product_name = container.find('a',{'itemprop':'name'}).text
        info = container.find_all('div',{'class':'col-xs-2 noPadding'})
        catNo = info[0].text.strip()
        size = info[1].text.strip()
        price = info[2].text.strip()

        print('Product_name: '+ product_name)
        print('CatNo: ' + catNo)
        print('Size: ' + size)
        print('Price: ' + price + '\n')

        f.write(','.join([product_name,catNo,size,price]))
```

Comment: Have you checked the size of `containers` to see if it's empty?

Comment: Also, you are not using `headers` string anywhere in your script. Do you mean `f.write(headers)` instead of `f.write('header')`?

Comment: @rahlf23 I tested out each of the containers individually to see if they would pull and they did but they wont pull when I put them all in the same script. Also Im not sure if becuase of the size of this page if that is also giving it issues.

Comment: I will post a simplified version of your script below for you to test. I can test this a bit later today on my home laptop without firewalls to ensure it works.

Comment: By the size of the page, do you mean that you need to scroll down to get access to the information that you need and it is loaded dynamically as you scroll? If so, then you almost certainly require `selenium`

Comment: Thank you so much this has been stumping me lately. When I say that the size is large I mean that there is a lot of information on this web page and not sure if that could be slowing it down. @rahlf23

Comment: If the content you are interested in extracting is not loaded dynamically, then I would be very surprised if the size of the content (quantity of information) is actually slowing you down...

Comment: @rahlf23 it is not a dynamic load as once everything is on the page nothing changes. I was able to scrape once I narrowed down the search results instead of doing all the products which I need. But now it is only pulling the first product and ending. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you update your OP to include your latest script? You could try changing `find()` to `find_all()` when assigning the product_name, however I don't think this is what you want. The URL you posted won't seem to load for me.

Comment: @rahlf23 I updated my OP with the code I am currently using. I have tried find_all but it doesn't seem to want to work. it just pulls the first product then stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166355/discussion-between-rahlf23-and-user9269112).

Answer (score 0):

Well the website you are using is technically loading information from a database, therefore it is not preset in the website HTML which product names are loaded by default. They must be loaded dynamically based on search constraints.

So you will need to download chromedriver.exe (if you use Google Chrome) or some other driver that automates your web browser (PhantomJS is another good one), then you will need to specify the path location on your machine to where this .exe lives, like so:

```
import selenium import webdriver
import csv, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

os.chdir('Path to chromedriver or other driver') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('Link to your webpage you want to extract HTML from')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

containers = soup.find_all('ul',{'id':'productsHolder'})

with open("BioLegend_Crawl.csv", "w") as f:

    f.write("Product_name, CatNo, Size, Price\n")

    for container in containers:

        product_name = container.find('a',{'itemprop':'name'}).text
        info = container.find_all('div',{'class':'col-xs-2 noPadding'})
        catNo = info[0].text.strip()
        size = info[1].text.strip()
        price = info[2].text.strip()

        print('Product_name: '+ product_name)
        print('CatNo: ' + catNo)
        print('Size: ' + size)
        print('Price: ' + price + '\n')

        f.write(','.join([product_name,catNo,size,price]))
```

Comment: inputed your code and followed all yours steps but now it seems to be giving me this error message 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Been playing around with it but still i am not able to pull anything also I updated my OP.

Comment: My answer is updated. `html` must be passed to `BeautifulSoup` in order to preserve the HTML tree structure to parse through.