# Python BeautifulSoup soup.find

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to scrape some specific data from a website using urllib and BeautifulSoup.
Im trying to fetch the text "190.0 kg". I have tried as you can see in my code to use `attrs={'class': 'col-md-7'}`
but this returns the wrong result. Is there any way to specify that I want it to return the text between `<h3>`?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
quote_page = 'https://.com'

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'    
page = urlopen(quote_page)

# parse the html using beautiful soup     
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# take out the <div> of name and get its value    
Weight_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'col-md-7'})

name = name_box.text.strip() 
print (name)
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual url?

Comment: What do you mean by *returns the wrong result*? Can you post the output you're getting?

Comment: Getting "Vis stream" instead. Searched the html for "Vis stream" and found that it is under col-md-7 visible-xs.

Comment: Updated the post with the real url.

Comment: @markusl2 check the page source. The content is not available, it is dynamically generated with Javascript. You can't scrape that simply using `requests` module. Have a look at [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: There are a few issues here: `soup.find` will only return the first match that it finds in the HTML structure. You will need to use `soup.find_all` in order to return a list of all matches. You may want to think about how you can narrow down your search to that specific tag instead. Finally, if you notice the `::before` prior to the `<div>` tag, the content you are interested in may be loaded dynamically. See a previous answer of mine here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49120065/8146556

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this content is dynamically generated there is no way to access that data using the `requests` module.

You can use `selenium webdriver` to accomplish this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

chrome_driver = "path_to_chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get('https://styrkeloft.no/live.styrkeloft.no/v2/?test-stevne')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
current_lifter = soup.find("div", {"id":"current_lifter"})
value = current_lifter.find_all("div", {'class':'row'})[2].find_all("h3")[0].text
driver.quit()

print(value)
```

Just be sure to have the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) executable in your machine.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider marking the answer as correct.